# Little help with SQL query and subquery

Tags: sql

I need a little help with creating a SQL query.  I have a table of user transactions that basically includes; transaction date, username, charge.

So, in a nutshell, this is what I want to do.  For a specified date range, add up all charges by username.  From that subquery table, I need to return a count of all user transactions sums that are between a specified range.

I was trying to break this down into three seperate subqueries but figured there might be an easier way, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the number of transaction sums where the transactions occur between two dates and the sum is in a particular range (between a lower and upper bound).

```
select count(*) as sum_count
from (
   select sum(charge) as total
   from transactions
   where transaction_date between @start_date and @end_date
   group by username) t
where total between @lower and @upper
```

Replace the parameters with actual values, use in a stored procedure with parameters, or set them (in code?) to values before running the query.

Comment: Ok, this is the subquery I have: 
<code>SELECT SUM(dbo_rpt_print_transactions.[Sheets]) as TOTAL FROM dbo_rpt_print_transactions WHERE (((dbo_rpt_print_transactions.[Date/Time]) Between #6/1/2010# And #12/30/2010#)) GROUP BY dbo_rpt_print_transactions.[User ID]; </code>

That returns the correct table of charges (Sheets in my case) by username that are in a date range. I am having trouble figuring out the rest of it though. What is SUM_COUNT?

Answer (score 0):

`select username, sum(charge), count(charge) 
from userTransactionTable 
where transaction_date between '01/01/2011' and '01/01/2012' 
group by username`